# tshark mark packets during capture?

Tags: wireshark, tshark

During a tshark packet capture session is it possible to automatically mark or somehow flag packets being captured in response to an external trigger? I want to be able to easily pick out potential packets of interest in a long unmonitored capture session.

What I am trying to achieve is an enhancement to my home security system whereby I capture all wifi probe requests and in the event of an alarm (or other external trigger) pick out the devices (device fingerprints) which were in the area at the time as an investigation aid.

I know I could just do this manually by comparing log times (this of course assumes both logs have same time baseline) but if the alarm could trigger a flag on even just a single packet at the point of trigger it would create a nice forensic link between the alarm log and the packet log.

Comment: Are you using tshark for Windows or Linux?

Comment: I'm using Linux